# SSRS 2005 TO SSRS 2008 Upgrade

Tags: ssrs-2008

We've been successful in upgrading our SSRS servers from 2005 to 2008. Now when we open our report, the report converts to 2008 and we can make changes to the designer and save. But when I click preview I get the following error in BIDS. Are we missing something?

```
System.ArgumentNullException: No message was deserialized prior to calling the DispatchChannelSink.
Parameter name: requestMsg
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.DispatchChannelSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpHandlerTransportSink.HandleRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandler.InternalProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem. When doing a network sniff of the data being exchanged between the BIDS client and our App Server the trace reported that the content type was TEXT/XML…however we use a binary formatter for client server communication so it should not have been text/xml and should have been just an HTTP post with an octet-stream content type.

Since BIDS is running as a separate process, however, the config file was not found in the application folder so remoting was using the default setting of SOAP formatter – thus the text/xml content type and the resulting errors.

Hence we need a binary formatter which we did by copying the config file into the same folder as the BIDS exe (on my system that path was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE  the preview then started working.